# Liferay 6.2 - (VM) Velocity template for asset publisher - how to get a variable that it is inside another variable?

Tags: liferay, velocity, liferay-velocity

I am designing a new template for my asset publisher to get all contents with a class

> com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle

from a specific site.

In my web content structure i have:
-Image

inside this image:

-there is tow Text variable

-one for Title

-one for Description
here is my structure code:

```
<root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US">
<dynamic-element dataType="image" fieldNamespace="wcm" indexType="keyword" localizable="true" name="myImage" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" required="false" showLabel="true" type="wcm-image" width="">
    <dynamic-element dataType="string" indexType="keyword" localizable="true" name="title" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" required="false" showLabel="true" type="text" width="small">
        <meta-data locale="en_US">
            <entry name="label">
                <![CDATA[Title]]>
            </entry>
            <entry name="predefinedValue">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </entry>
            <entry name="tip">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </entry>
        </meta-data>
    </dynamic-element>
    <dynamic-element dataType="string" indexType="keyword" localizable="true" name="desc" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" required="false" showLabel="true" type="text" width="small">
        <meta-data locale="en_US">
            <entry name="label">
                <![CDATA[Description]]>
            </entry>
            <entry name="predefinedValue">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </entry>
            <entry name="tip">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </entry>
        </meta-data>
    </dynamic-element>
    <meta-data locale="en_US">
        <entry name="label">
            <![CDATA[Image]]>
        </entry>
        <entry name="predefinedValue">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </entry>
        <entry name="tip">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </entry>
    </meta-data>
</dynamic-element>
```

and here is how it's appears : 
[Screenshot of my structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozNXj.png)

Now i wrote this code in my asset template using (VM) or Velocity Macros

```
#if (!$entries.isEmpty())

#foreach ($entry in $entries)
    #set($renderer = $entry.getAssetRenderer() )
    #set($className = $renderer.getClassName() )

    #if( $className == "com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle" )
        #set( $journalArticle = $renderer.getArticle() )
        #set( $document = $saxReaderUtil.read($journalArticle.getContent()) )
        #set( $rootElement = $document.getRootElement() )

        #foreach( $dynamicElement in $rootElement.elements() )
            #if( "myImage" == $dynamicElement.attributeValue("name") )
                #set( $myImage = $dynamicElement.element("dynamic-content").getText() ) 
                #end

        <img src="$myImage" > 
        #end

    #end
#end
```

## end

from this code i can reach my image, but my problem is that i cannot find a way to get the variables inside the image , one with name="title" and another with name="desc" ? 
So, i need to reach these tow text variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the simplest way to examine data from structure fields is to print the variable and look what is inside. I took structure from your post. So i've created a structure then article based on it.

[image]

Then i've printed the `$myImage` variable and it looks like this:

```
{name=myImage, data=/image/journal/article?img_id=22009&t=1503342749476, type=image, options=[], title={name=title, data=colorful bird, type=text, options=[]}, desc={name=desc, data=this is a birdie, type=text, options=[]}}
```

So as you can see it contains an image, title and description so to extract them, just use(THIS IS MY TEMPLATE CODE FOR SCREEN BELOW):

```
$myImage
$myImage.title.getData()
$myImage.desc.getData()
```

Final effect with $myImage printed:
[image]

If you want a name attribute just use `$myImage.title.name`, it will give you what is inside of name.

**EDIT**
Ok, I'm sorry i misread your question. You are creating the asset publisher template not article template. So i think your way is the right way to display embedded variables. Below is your modified template that displays image, title, and description:

```
#foreach ($entry in $entries)
    #set($renderer = $entry.getAssetRenderer() )
    #set($className = $renderer.getClassName() )

    #if( $className == "com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle" )
        #set( $journalArticle = $renderer.getArticle() )
        #set( $document = $saxReaderUtil.read($journalArticle.getContent()) )
        #set( $rootElement = $document.getRootElement() )

        #foreach( $dynamicElement in $rootElement.elements() )
            #if( "myImage" == $dynamicElement.attributeValue("name") )
                #set( $myImage = $dynamicElement.element("dynamic-content").getText() ) 
            #end
            #foreach( $embeddedElement in $dynamicElement.elements() )
                #if( "title" == $embeddedElement.attributeValue("name") )
                    #set( $title = $embeddedElement.elements().get(0).getText() ) 
                #end
                #if( "desc" == $embeddedElement.attributeValue("name") )
                    #set( $desc = $embeddedElement.elements().get(0).getText() ) 
                #end
            #end 
            <br/>
            <img src="$myImage" > 
            <br/>
            <br/>
            Title: $title
            <br/>
            Description: $desc
        #end

    #end
#end
```

And the effect:
[image]

Comment: On the screen is final effect and template code is posted above :). It looks like this 
`$myImage` - this prints the whole variable shown above.
`$myImage.title.getData()` -  this prints the nested title.
`$myImage.desc.getData()` - this prints the nested description. I've edited my answer

Comment: okay i understand you , but i want to know where to place this code in my template :)